# Sidebar icons from non-system volume disappears after restart in Finder of Mac OSX 10.8.2

Tags: macos, finder

I dragged folders in finder to Favorite in sidebar. Folders from system volume survived after system restarts but folders from non-system volume are gone. This problem happens since I upgraded from Lion. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the disk/share isn't mounted, the favorite is removed from the sidebar.  If you want to keep favorites to network shares, removable disks, or files in disk images, there is a workaround.

Create a new folder named "Remote Favorites".  This can be anywhere on your local disk (Home folder, Documents, etc)
Drag the Remote Favorites folder to your sidebar
Add aliases of the remote file/folder into the Remote Favorites folder.  (hold option+command while dragging the source file)

The Remote Favorites folder is local so it won't disappear from your Sidebar.
Now when you need to get to one of these remote files, open the Remote Favorites folder and double click the alias of the remote file.

Another benefit of using aliases is that if the network share or disk image isn't mounted, it will automatically mount it first.